# after installing ubuntu 12.10 the desktop does not display correctly

Tags: 12.10, display, vmware, vmware-player

I've installed vmware player on my windows 7 in order to run ubuntu 12.10..
The ubuntu installation went well with no errors or display faults, but after restarting the vm at the end of the installation process i get the desktop with no visible sidebar or any menu bars at all.. They are active but the graphics is all black or corrupted.

please help.
thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems running Ubuntu 12.10 in VMWare Player 5](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218296/problems-running-ubuntu-12-10-in-vmware-player-5)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 2D working fine, but not Ubuntu virtual machine in VMWare Wokstation 9 Windows 7 Host](http://askubuntu.com/questions/437041/ubuntu-2d-working-fine-but-not-ubuntu-virtual-machine-in-vmware-wokstation-9-wi)

Answer (score 2):

on vmware player
Do "Edit virtual Machine settings"
On "Hardware tab" go to "Display"
Clear "Accelerate 3D graphics"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with 12.10.

I installed 12.04 and was able to send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> command to log off... then i changed the option to ubuntu 2d before logging on and everything worked fine.

Not sure if that option works under 12.10... but it def worked for me under 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue... The installed version of the VMware Player on my host machine was 4, so i upgraded to 5. After that I checked the `Accelerate 3D graphics` option in the `display settings` of the `virtual machine`. Everything went fine from there.

Execute `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` and check if Unity 3D support is available.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system specs, Ubuntu may not work on virtual boxes... Specially 12.10, as they dropped Unity 2D and replaced it with an "alternative" version which uses **llvmpipe** instead of **OpenGL**.

So probably your system isn't capable to virtualize Ubuntu 12.10. Try virtualizing 12.04, which still has Unity 2D, or some alternative versions like Xubuntu, which uses the **XFCE** desktop environment, or **Lubuntu**, which uses LXDE. Both of them are lightweight, ideal for low-end systems or virtual machines (specially LXDE).