# VMware 9.0 - Ubuntu Screen Problem

Tags: 12.04, display, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu 12.4 on VMware Workstation, but I'm not getting display, I mean there is something strange for me. I can access the terminal when i Press Ctrl+T but i can't see the icons and left side menu bar.

[Check it out the Screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/vdffbz75j/)
Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue Please ?

Thanks !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems running Ubuntu 12.10 in VMWare Player 5](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218296/problems-running-ubuntu-12-10-in-vmware-player-5)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem encountered. fixed !by turn off 3D Acceleration in vmware.
Go to "Virtual Machine Settings" , click "Display",then Uncheck "Accelerate 3D graphics"
enjoy!