# Ubuntu 2D working fine, but not Ubuntu virtual machine in VMWare Workstation 9 Windows 7 Host

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, virtualization, vmware

I'm using Windows 7 as the host machine with VMWare Workstation 9. I created a virtual machine Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS 64 bit version. There are two options for log in, Ubuntu and Ubuntu 2D. Whenever I log in to Ubuntu, the task bar will not show up, is like having a black margin all around the desktop background and only the center is visible. 
I wish I could attached a pic, but I need at least 10 reputation.

When I move my mouse over the left side of the desktop I can see that something is there but it is shown only as a black square. I tried deleting the virtual machine I created for Ubuntu and re-installed it, but it keeps appearing like that.  When I switched to log in with the Ubuntu 2D version everything worked alright. I could see the task bar, the icons, the clock etc.
What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3):

OK I fixed it! I just needed to turn off 3D Acceleration in the VMware. On the menu bar go to VM > Settings > Display > Uncheck Accelerate 3D graphics. ;)

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it the same way. Voting you up for referencing to the problem.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way how to get the 3D desktop working. Clues anyone?