# Menu is not visible on ubuntu using VMwareWorkstation 10 on windows 8

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, vmware-workstation

I am new to linux distribution.

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on windows 8.1 (VMware Workstation 10). I have managed to successfully install it, however I do not see the menu when 3D is on in Workstation and ubuntu is very slow  if 3D is switched off.

[image: screenshot]

How do I get this resolved: The menu to appear when 3D in on?

Comment: VMware is a company, what product are you using(Player, Workstation, etc.)? Can you please upload a screenshot when the menu is absent? And where exactly are you switching between 3D and otherwise?

Comment: here is where in VmWare 10 
http://uptobox.com/urxlfeby7v8r

Comment: Can you check if the solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/218335/72576) or [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) helps?

Comment: Can you open a terminal in ubuntu using ctrl + alt + t and then type `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ ` and then `unity --reset-icons &disown` and see if it helps?

Comment: i get this, but it was mutch long log. i just put the end :

root@ubuntu:~# dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
root@ubuntu:~# unity --reset-icons &disown
[1] 3330
root@ubuntu:~# stop: Unknown job: unity-panel-service
start: Unknown job: unity-panel-service
ERROR 2014-05-27 12:34:06 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'
ERROR 2014-05-27 12:34:07 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.Unity'

Comment: so it simce that there is NO Possibility in VmWare/VirtualBox to sold this probleme!! 
...... !!!!! Ubuntu

Comment: Paste the complete error log to pastebin.ubuntu.com and post the link here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution : go to settings >> display >> uncheck at 3D graphics: Accelerate 3D graphics.
I tried and it worked for me.

Comment: He mentioned this in the question; with 3D turned off, he's experiencing performance issues.